# Trying to fit a Distinct() into a relatively complex LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query so far:

```
 var msg = ModelState.Values
                   .Where(x => x.Errors.Any())
                   .Select(c => c.Errors.Select(d => d.ErrorMessage).Aggregate((e, f) => (e ?? "") + "<br/>" + f))
                   .Aggregate((x, y) => (x ?? "") + "<br/>" + y);
```

This is working perfectly, but I need to filter out the duplicate error messages. I have tried adding both GroupBy() and Distinct() to several places both prior to and following the predicate that obtains the ErrorMessage. What am I missing?

If I run this as it is, I receive the following result:

```
"Contact Email address invalid<br/>Contact Email address invalid"
```

Each ErrorMessage value here is "Contact Email address invalid". These are the duplicates that I would like to filter out.

Comment: Is `ErrorMessage` just a string or an object?  If it;s just a string then `c.Errors.Select(d => d.ErrorMessage).Distinct().Aggregate` should work

Comment: Yes, ErrorMessage is a string, but no, that unfortunately does not work. When I execute that I receive the following out: "Contact Email address invalid<br/>Contact Email address invalid". It should just be "Contact Email address invalid". I will add this to the initial post.

Comment: I would take a close look at the error messages and see if there's any whitespace or other characters that's throwing off the `Distinct` check.

Comment: I added a Trim() to ErrorMessage but the result did not change. :\

Comment: `Select(o => o.Select(...).Aggregate(...))` is usually a sign that you want to be using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Using Aggregate() with strings makes me cringe.

Comment: @CSharpie it's certainly novel, I'll give them that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest an alternative?

Assuming you want distinct messages, separated by the break tag:

```
var items = ModelState.Values
    .SelectMany(c => c.Errors.Select(d => d.ErrorMessage))
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

string msg = string.Join("<br/>", items);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've got two places producing values.  Consider the following case:

```
Value   Errors
1.      "Bad username", "Contact Email address invalid"
2.      "Contact Email address invalid"
```

Even if you add `Distinct` to both `Select` calls, it won't do what you want, as `Bad username<br/>Contact Email address invalid` will be compared to `Contact Email address invalid`, will be found not to be equal, and will be aggregated into `Bad username<br/>Contact Email address invalid<br/>Contact Email address invalid`, which, I assume, is not what you want.

Instead, you should be flattening the nested lists of errors first.  This is the job of [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx).  To flatten your list, you just need to do:

```
var errorMessages = ModelState.Values
               .Where(x => x.Errors.Any())
               .SelectMany(c => c.Errors.Select(d => d.ErrorMessage))
```

Now `errorMessages` is a list of *every* error message from every `Value`. (Note that the `Where` is *probably* unneeded: `Select` or `SelectMany` on an empty sequence is a no-op.)

Now there is the second issue:

It is almost always bad practice to use `+` with strings in C#, due to `string`'s immutablity.  Instead, you want to use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx), [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), or [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) depending on if your input is a sequence, multiple variables or longer strings.  In this case you have an array, so `string.Join` is the tool of choice:

```
var msg = string.Join("<br/>", errorMessages.Distinct())
```

Comment: This is what all Stack Overflow answers should look like. Not just "here, take my code".

Comment: Your explanation should play role of a checksum. :)

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation, RoadieRich. Not sure of the proper etiquette here, but I gave Joe Enos the vote for Answer since his response was first. When I try to up-vote yours, I get a message about being too newbie to have my vote count. :( Nevertheless, I thank you very much - your response is appreciated.

Comment: @TheLurkingDev you should accept whichever one you think is the best answer.